# How to add background image for input type="button"?

Tags: html, css, button

i've been trying to change the background image of the input button through css, but it doesn't work.

search.html:

```
<body>
    <form name="myform" class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="q" onkeyup="showUser()" />
        <input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="showUser()" class="button"/>
         <p>
             <div id="txtHint"></div>
         </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

search.css:

```
.button {
    background-image: url ('/image/btn.png') no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

what could be wrong?

even inline-ing the css didn't seem to work.

Comment: You should be using `<input type="image" />` instead

Comment: when i tried that, it displayed no results at all. anyhow, thanks to jonathan it;s working now.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to type it without the word `image`.

`background: url('/image/btn.png') no-repeat;`

Tested both ways and this one works.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .button{
                background: url(/image/btn.png) no-repeat;
                cursor:pointer;
                border: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="showUser()" class="button"/>
        <input type="image" name="button" value="Search" onclick="showUser()" class="button"/>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Search" onclick="showUser()" class="button"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: funny. it doesn't work for me. 

the firebug console only shows this: `.button {
cursor:pointer;
}
`

Comment: Did you try to copy and paste the whats in the code box into an html file to see if that works for you? Also try using quotes around the path or remove the first `/`.

Comment: k, it works now [the type="button" one that is]! thanks. i wonder what was wrong with the external css. the only thing now is that it shows the image as the background of the button with the borders. how can i just show the image, without it looking like a button?

Comment: The code for that is just like any old div or table tag. `border: none;`

Comment: how to set the size of the image and how to have variable image?

Answer (score 16):

Just to add to the answers, I think the specific reason in this case, in addition to the misplaced `no-repeat`, is the space between `url` and `(`:

```
background-image: url ('/image/btn.png') no-repeat; /* Won't work */
background-image: url('/image/btn.png'); /* Should work */
```

Comment: Actually I just tried it and your right! It does not work with the space but that's not the only problem with your code.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. i was googling for solutions on this, and one of the answers was with `no-repeat`, hence i tried it.

Comment: url(/buttonsimages/redheart.jpg)// THIS DONT WORK FOR ME: STARTING URL WITH SLASH url(buttonsimages/redheart.jpg)// THIS WORK FOR ME: STARTING URL WITH TEXT

Answer (score 10):

`background-image` takes an url as a value. Use either

```
background-image: url ('/image/btn.png');
```

or

```
background: url ('/image/btn.png') no-repeat;
```

which is a shorthand for

```
background-image: url ('/image/btn.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Also, you might want to look at the [`button` HTML element](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/) for fancy submit buttons.

Answer (score 4):

If this is a submit button, use `<input type="image" src="..." ... />`.

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_IMAGE.html

If you want to specify the image with CSS, [you'll have to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-input-button-image-using-css) `type="submit"`.

Comment: Type `image` and `submit` both act as submit so you can catch the submit event via the `form` tag attribute `onSubmit`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536972(VS.85).aspx

Comment: If you look at my code that I tested and is working, `input type="button"` and `input type="image"` can be styled using css. He just used the wrong property.

Comment: the problem is, when i use `type="submit"` the form reloads but displays no results; but when i use `type="button"`, the results are displayed. the data is being generated via ajax on the click of the button, and the form doesn't have any handler called 'onsubmit'.

Comment: If you're loading via AJAX, then you'd move the call to the `onSubmit` event, otherwise you're calling (I presume) via `onClick` and the form is being submitted as well.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button{
    background-image:url('/image/btn.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to a ten year old question with an accepted answer it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button-class {
  background: url(images/tom1.png) no-repeat; /* local source or link */
  cursor: pointer; /* if you want different cursor */
  border: none;
}
```

OR

```css
#button-id {
  background: url(images/img.png) no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```