# image button in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use image for button as:

```
<button name="foo" type="button" value="bar" onclick="AjaxResponse()" > <img src="img.png"> </button>
```

or

```
 <button name="foo" type="button" value="bar" onclick="AjaxResponse()" img src="img.png" />
```

Both does not show button with image. It just shows small icon, which performs correct operation on click. But why the image could not be seen?

Comment: Why not just do it in CSS with `background-image`.

Comment: Are you sure the path to your image is correct?

Comment: Use input type image http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_src.asp. And both your html codes are incorrect.

Comment: Karimkhan, Did u tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738920/background-image-for-input-type-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `width` and `height` correctly.Like

```
<img src="something" width=200 height=200>
```

Otherwise use div tag to create custom button with the help of CSS.

Go through this you can get some idea [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-an-input-button-image-using-css)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `<img>` tag and add `onClick` to it:

```
<img src="img.png" onclick="AjaxResponse()" />
```

In addition, you can set the width and height according to your picture's dimensions:

```
<img src="img.png" onclick="AjaxResponse()" width="100" height="100" />
```

However, the CSS `background-image` property is probably the best solution. There you can also adjust `width` and `height`.

Comment: the img element doesn't have a closing tag :-(

Comment: @jeff I normally use ´XHTML´, where all tags have to be closed, but I edited the answer.

Comment: This correct syntax is <img src ... /> XHTML has been depreciated and hasn't been updated since 1999. Use html 5 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of PHP, this is in your HTML part and you can't do this without CSS or you can use:

```
<input type="image" ...
```

to know more read the following link: [Input Types](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

OR take a look on CSS: [background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="image" src="FILEPATH" onclick="AjaxResponse()" name="foo" id="button" value="bar">
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use css, you can use the input like this,

```
input type="image" src="img.png" name="foo" type="button" alt="bar" onclick="AjaxResponse()"
```