# How to use button instead input, style input?

Tags: css, forms, jsp, servlets, post

My form:

```
<form method="POST" action="AController">
    <div class="userInput">
        <table class="userInput">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="username" name="login"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="submitRegInput" name="reg"
                    value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to style

```
<input type="submit" id="submitRegInput" name="reg" value="Submit">
```

like this:

```
#submitRegInput {
background: no-repeat url(../images/okBtn.png) 0 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work.
My AController :

```
if (req.getParameter("reg") != null) {
//doSmthingHere
}
```

How to change input to button:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitRegInput">
    <img src="images/okBtn.png" height="40" width="40" />
</button>
```

so it does same job as input submit button did? Or what is the way to style input type=submit button with image?

Comment: url path must be between quotes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738920/background-image-for-input-type-button This answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsp form button instead of input:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitRegInput" name="reg">
           <img src="images/okBtn.png"/>
</button>
```

and css:

```
#submitRegInput {
background: no-repeat url(../images/okBtn.png) 0 0;
border: none;
}
```