# Icon for Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need samples or some guidance on how to replace the back button with some icon (any) .actually working on multipage app and back button has to be replaced with any icons

```html
<script>
  $.getScript(path + "js/Page1.js");
</script>

<p id="currentPage"></p>
<div class="container">
  <label>WRKID</label>
  <input type="text" id="wrkid">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>WRKNAME</label>
  <input type="text" id="wrkname">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>REFID</label>
  <input type="text" id="Refid">
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="appButton" value="INSERT" onclick="insert();">
<br>
<br>

<input type="button" id="backButtonPage2" class="appButton" value="BACK" onclick="currentPage.back();" />
```

```js
currentPage = {};

currentPage.init = function() {
  WL.Logger.debug("Page1 :: init");
};
currentPage.back = function() {
  WL.Logger.debug("Page1 :: back");
  $("#pagePort").load(pagesHistory.pop());
};
```

Comment: @idanadar isn't it related to mobile first

Comment: Nope. This is pure HTML/CSS.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738920/background-image-for-input-type-button

Answer (score -3):

```js
currentPage = {};

currentPage.init = function() {
  WL.Logger.debug("Page1 :: init");
};
currentPage.back = function() {
  WL.Logger.debug("Page1 :: back");
  $("#pagePort").load(pagesHistory.pop());
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.12/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```