# How to align text at center over image inside button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have divided an html page into four sections. I have created four buttons inside it which contain images. I also want text to be displayed at the center of each button. But due to the images the texts are moving below the button. Please tell me how to achieve this.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

button img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Nature</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514361107497-ca601745d27a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="">Himalaya</button>

  <button><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508831084156-40f6573bbe6b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt=""></button>

  <button><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585889574476-af7bcb00d9c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt=""></button>

  <button><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543763479-fb7533fcbf3b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt=""></button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-image: url('https://someurl.com');`
instead of placing the image inside the button tag.

See: [How to add background image for input type="button"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738920/how-to-add-background-image-for-input-type-button)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS property `background-image` to set the background of the image for a css property, and you can use your `text-align` to center the text:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Nature</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <button style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514361107497-ca601745d27a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80')">Himalaya</button>

  <button style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508831084156-40f6573bbe6b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80')"></button>

  <button style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585889574476-af7bcb00d9c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80')"></button>

  <button style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543763479-fb7533fcbf3b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80')"></button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 possibiities:

1.) Use an element with `position: absolute` for the text

or

2.) Use the images as background-images

Comment: You should explain how.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you could use background-image instead of `img` elements. But on hover, `opacity:0.4` will apply to both image and text. If you want to keep the text at `opacity:1` on hover, wrap up the text in a span and position it `absolute` center it, and apply opacity on hover to `img` only:

HTML:

```
<button><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514361107497-ca601745d27a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt=""><span>Himalaya</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

button img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
button span {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   text-align: center;
}
button:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1q879w3p/