# background-image without background

Tags: html, css

I am using button with `background-image` property set. Image I'm using is partially transparent and by default it has grey background. When I tried to use `background: transparent/white`, suddenly my image no longer scales, although I use `background-size: cover/contain`.

Is there a way to achieve this without using `<img>` inside button?

Or perhaps is there a way to change HTML properties with CSS?
Because I am forging HTML in java and it's simpler to use CSS classes with `background-image` than to add `<img>` every time.

EDIT: Suggested answer: [How to add background image for input type="button"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738920/how-to-add-background-image-for-input-type-button) doesn't cover my question, although solution appears there in comments but for different reason. Said question is about adding background image to `<input type="button">` which is different from my `<button>` and I had no problem with adding image in the first place (my image was added) and in mentioned question the problem laid in a typo.

To make it more clear my code was:

```
<button style="background-image: url('/path/to/my/image'); background-size: cover;">
```

and it worked fine, but - since image itself was transparent in some places - there was grey background visible from underneath. When I changed my code to:

```
<button style="background-image: url('/path/to/my/image'); background-size: cover; background: transparent;">
```

I got rid of grey background but my image did not scale down to the button width anymore.

Changing it to use `background: url('/path/to/my/image');` resolved the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add background image for input type="button"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738920/how-to-add-background-image-for-input-type-button)

Comment: Please could you put your code into the question. It's impossible to tell what is happening from just the description, though I'm suspicious of setting background: transparent as opposed to background-color: transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `background` instead of `background-image`

The CSS code :

```
background: url('../image/button.png') no-repeat;
```

Example :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .btn{
                background: url(../image/button.png) no-repeat;
                cursor:pointer;
                border: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="submitForm">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="button" value="Search"/>
     </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Another way you can try with 
background-image: url(../image/button.png);

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with `input` tag of `type="imge"`

```html
<input type="image" id="image" alt="Login"
       src="/media/examples/login-button.png">
```

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image)

OR, you can add background-image as shown below:

```css
.btn{
  width:200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(//unsplash.it/800);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor:pointer;
  border: none;
  }
```

```html
<form>
   <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: not really as I need this button to be of type 'submit' to send POST query onclick

Comment: @jbulatek you can set the onClick property and then take the data from the `form` and make the `POST` request