# IE6 input button image background

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Is it possible to make your own background image for input type="button" for IE6?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-input-button-image-using-css

Comment: Does `background-image` not work?

Comment: for input type="button"!

For button it does not works.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Post an URL or show some code. And make sure that the image URL is correct. Have you tried it with something else than a button?

Comment: Yes, with everything else like type="img " or "submit" it works. But not with button. In IE6.

Comment: You're still doing something wrong. [Here is a test page](http://jsfiddle.net/dkLU8/). I see the image in IE6.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You'll need to remove the border: `border: none`

Comment: I removed it and now i want to add a backgroud image.

Comment: Deleted mine in favour of this.  I would recommend `<button>` instead of `<input>`, but this more directly answers the question.

Comment: Technically it answers the question, but it doesn't explain *how* to do it, which the OP probably wants to know (as do I)