# CSS image for submit button - clicking image must submit form

Tags: css, wordpress, forms

Please help,

I have a form on wordpress. I want the user to be able to click an image instead of the standard submit button.

I have the image appear and the submit button disappear - but nothing happens when I click on the image.

This is the code I am using:

```
.formBuilderForm .formBuilderSubmit {
clear: both;
text-align: right;
    display:block;
width:228px;
height:49px;
background: url(my image url) no-repeat;
text-indent:-999em;
```

Before you say "google it" or try search:
I have tried the methods mentioned here:
http://www.queness.com/post/798/5-techniques-to-style-buttons-using-images-and-css

I've read similar posts such as this on stackoverflow but they don't solve my frustratingly simple problem.
[How to change an input button image using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-input-button-image-using-css)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show the related HTML as well. Also are you aware of the `<input type="image">` element?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I am aware of it - however the submit button is part of a wordpress plugin and I don't really want to go hacking it up. In the documentation of this plugin developer says elements can be edited using css without impact - so that's why i'm taking this approach.

Answer (score 1):

put this instead of a submit button

```
<input type="image" src="http://imageurl">
```

Comment: thanks - but the submit button is part of a wordpress plugin and I don't want to go hacking about in it.

Comment: n the documentation of this plugin developer says elements can be edited using css without impact - so that's why i'm taking this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just In case anyone cares:
This was an issue with the FormBuilder Wordpress Plugin.
I used very similar css using Contact Form 7 and it worked.

```
padding:8px 0 10px 0px;
color:#FF0000;
border:none;
width:107px;
height:26px;
text-align:center;
background-image:url(the url went here);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-indent:-999em;
```

Thanks for the help.