# Using two images as submit's for a form

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change an input button image using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-an-input-button-image-using-css)

Is it possible to use two images as submit buttons for a form?

I have a language selection page with two flags (.png's) on it, I want it so when the user clicks on a flag it submits the form.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/195637/794234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:document.myform.submit()" name="flag1">
    <img src="img1.png" width="20" height="10" alt="" />
</a>

<a href="javascript:document.myform.submit()" name="flag2">
    <img src="img2.png" width="20" height="10" alt="" />
</a>
```

That should work for you :) Just remember to change `javascript:document.myform.submit()` to the `name` attribute of your form element.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to attach a value to the submit as well? Just so I can use $_GET?

Comment: @Rob: That should be done with the form. `method="get"`.

Comment: @Purmou So it's not possible to give each image/link a different value such as `value="UK"`?

Comment: @Rob: Well, sure, you can customize the data that is submitted with the for, but that's when you should get into jQuery to handle the submission. You can prevent the default submission and gather the values yourself and submit it that way.

Comment: @Rob the value of the `name` attribute on the anchor should be automatically submitted with the form, so that will tell the script which one the user clicked on.

Comment: @ChrisClower Ok that's great.

Comment: @Rob: Look for my updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with inline events, but I recommend using either pure Javascript or jQuery to do it. jQuery covers cross-browser implementations for you.

For example (with jQuery):

```
$("#imgID").click(function(){
    $("#formID").submit();
});
```

Comment: There is no jQuery in the question!

Comment: @Amberlamps: Am I not allowed to recommend it?

Comment: You had only posted your code snippet when I commented on your answer.

Comment: @Amberlamps: I do that to get my answer in first--then I edit it accordingly.

Comment: Why you do that? Do not complain if people do not get the gist when they can only read half of your answer.

Comment: @Amberlamps: ...I do it to get my answer in first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript like

```
<img src="image.png" onclick="submit_form()" />
<img src="image.png" onclick="submit_form()" />
```

**JavaScript function**

```
function submit_form()
{
  // If you want to change action then

  document.form_name.action="your action";

  document.form_name.submit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for also passing a parameter:

```
<form name="FormularName">
    <input type="hidden" name="valueField" />
    <a href="#" onclick="submit_form('Flag1')"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="submit_form('Flag2)"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function submit_form(value) {
    document.FormularName.valueField.value = value;
    document.FormularName.submit()
}
```

Comment: Eh, inline event handling isn't really the best option here, but is one nonetheless. :)

Comment: @Purmou: Please explain why inline event handling is not the best answer here!

Comment: It's not neat and and harder to maintain if you have other Javascript in a separate file or on other parts of the page. Just keep every aspect of your site separate--layout (HTML), design (CSS), and functionalities (Javascript).

Comment: I generally agree with you, when you have some processing to do. But when you have just a function call, you might want to keep that in your element.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of style then.