# Replacing image with CSS on Django if/else statement

Tags: html, css, django, image, if-statement

I am trying to create a voting system similar to that of stackoverflow, but I can't figure out how to call on the css instead of the images.

I have the following code:

```
 <input type="image" id="uparrow{{ vote.id }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}static/img/aup{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}mod{% else %}grey{% endif %}.PNG">
```

How can I change the code so it calls a css class instead of an img src?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-an-input-button-image-using-css) could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like:

```
<input type="image" id="uparrow{{ vote.id }}" 
       src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}static/img/vote.png"
       class="otherclass {% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}upvote{% else %}novote{% endif %}" />
```

The image would have classes "otherclass" and "upvote" in one case, "otherclass" and "novote" in the other.

Comment: Iserni if it only pulls the css arrows, do I still need the src image.png?

Comment: The image input type requires a src, if you want to specify it by css, use a regular submit button in stead.