# Background image for button in IE6 html

Tags: html

The below coding is how I add a background image on a button on my webpage. It can work on IE9, Firefox and Chrome:

```
   <td>
   <input id="btn1" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-image: url('images/refresh.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;" type="button" onclick="Get()"/>  
   </td>
```

But when I use IE6, it does not show the image. Just an empty button.

Do you guys know how do we put the image on a button that will shown on IE9 as well as IE6?

Answer (score 1):

you could use `<input type='image'>` It defines an image as the submit button.

Comment: Are we able to detect what browser we are using in html? Is it that I should put: if (IE6) {<input type='image'>} else if (IE9) {<input type='button'>}. Is it like this?

Comment: you could refer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="image" src="">`. It works fine with IE and others browsers.

This is the W3C Recommendation:

"*The image button state represents either an image from which a user can select a coordinate and submit the form, or alternatively a button from which the user can submit the form. The element is a button, specifically a submit button*."

Or you can use this hack (I mean, it's preferable using the input image.):

```
<div class="button"><input type="submit" name="" value=""></div>
```

And the CSS file:

```
div.button input {
    background:url(/images/Btn.PNG) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: none;
}
```

Source of the last recommendation is: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1193338/2356834) :)