# Change rails button_to helper into button_tag helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use an icon on a Twitter intent button.

```
<%= button_to "Share on Twitter", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=#{@twitter_message}", :class => "btn" %>
```

Is it possible?

There are 2 other buttons on the page using button_tag helpers and I can insert the icons into those buttons. Should I convert the button_to into a button_tag and if so how?

Comment: [There's a lengthy discussion on adding image into `input` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-an-input-button-image-using-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `button_to` [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to), it generates an input tag:

```
<%= button_to "New", action: "new" %>

<form method="post" action="/controller/new" class="button_to">
   <div><input value="New" type="submit" /></div>
</form>"
```

So you should use link_to instead, with a button class, like:

```
<%= link_to "Share on Twitter", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=#{@twitter_message}", :class => "btn icon-edit" %>
```

I've done this using twitter [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: One up for the difference based on input tag generated. Nice tip.

Answer (score 1):

Why to not use `link_to` instead, as more suitable for your case.

```
link_to 'http://tweeter.com/bla-bla', class: 'btn' do
    # Your text and icon
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<%= button_to "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=#{@twitter_message}", :class => "btn" do %>
   <i class="icon-something"></i>Share on Twitter
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've tried this but I get the http string as the text on the button. Screen shot of part of the button http://imgur.com/Xa36NpW

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?