# I Need Help Changing A Submit Button Image to Another Image When The Mouse Hovers Over It

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to make my submit button image change to another image when the cursor hovers over it. Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<body>

<form>
<font face="Arial">Please type your name below and click submit.</font>
<br />
<input type="text">
<p>
<input type="image" src="..\Pictures\submit_button_img.jpg" alt="submit" >
</p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

This code works, I just don't know how to switch the image when the cursor hovers over it. Any suggestions? I'd like it to be in CSS or JavaScript, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change an input button image using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-an-input-button-image-using-css)

Answer (score 4):

use

```
<input type="submit" class="somename">
```

and add a `class` name that has the image set as a `background-image` and then use CSS `:hover` to change that image. No Javascript needed

```
  input[type=submit]{
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("someimage.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    text-indent: -9999px;
  }

  input[type=submit]:hover{
    background-image: url("someimage2.jpg");
 }
```

You can target the submit button or you can add a class name, either way. You can also use a sprite and change the `background-position` on hover instead of swapping image files

quick example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4eb77/)

Comment: That's not really an option, the submit button won't magically turn into an image, like the image input type ?

Comment: what? How is that not an option, that's how it's done

Comment: Sure, show me a working fiddle and I'll believe you

Comment: haha well 4 people upvoted this so im pretty sure im not making it up. check out the code above, that's how it's done. Ill add a fiddle though

Comment: Please do, and note that the OP is using `<input type="image" ...`

Comment: @adeneo http://jsfiddle.net/zero298/SnVhF/

Comment: im aware of the OP, that's not the proper way to do it

Comment: @zero298 - now you've completely changed a button to look like an image, which has issues of it's own.

Comment: @adeneo What are you talking about?  It's a `button` it does everything a button does but instead of text, it has an image.

Comment: @adeneo here is a quick example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eb77/)

Comment: That's great, but the OP is actually using the correct tag, an input with the type of image to show an image as a submit button, that's why it was implented, as buttons generally should be styled as buttons, and in older browsers you couldn't even do this, and you've just changed an input with a type of button to an image with a lot of styling, to get what the OP has without having to do much of anything, doesn't make any sense to me ?

Comment: @adeneo: I'm trying everything that you've been talking about, even the jsfiddle stuff, but it's not working.

Comment: @user3174656 adeneo hasn't posted an answer, this is my response, what isn't working?

Comment: @jmore: Oh, sorry. I'm trying everyone's answers, but none of them seem to be working.

Comment: @user3174656 im using `input type="submit"` you're using `input type="image"`, im suggesting you change the input type to `submit` then try my code

Comment: @jmore009: I tried that.

Comment: @user3174656 do you have a link?

Comment: @jmore009 A link to what?

Comment: @jmore009 I got it to work. Thanks anyways, though. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should use a sprite. It's a great way to do rollovers without that "flash of emptiness" before the second image loads.

First, create your sprite. It should be one image that looks like this:

```
+---------------+
| Normal button |
+---------------+
+---------------+
| Hover  button |
+---------------+
```

Note that the two "parts" should be the same size as each other, and this will be the size of your button. Save this, for example as `btn_sheet.png`

Now you need to prepare your input:

```
<input type="image" class="btnimage" />
```

And now for the CSS that makes it all work:

```css
.btnimage {
    width: 100px; /* replace with actual width your button */
    height: 50px; /* replace with actual height of the button */
    background:url('/btn_sheet.png'); /* adjust path as needed */
}
.btnimage:hover {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
    /* replace the 50px with the actual height of the button */
}
```

And done!

Comment: awesome, it works, but on the second image that it switches to, it has the submit button text on it. any way to remove it?

Comment: Hmm... try adding `value=""` to the HTML?

Comment: yup, that's exactly what i did, to be honest.

Comment: Haha! Well, glad you figured it out :)

Comment: well, it was... not sure why it stopped working lol

Comment: i've tried a bunch of stuff and still can't get it