# How to make a picture act like a button

Tags: html, css

I trying to make a button with an image as a background like this:

HTML

```
<input type="image" value="submit" src="images/map.png" id="location" />
```

and This is the css content (in a seperate css file)

```
#location{
position: fixed;
right: 10px;
bottom: 20px;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
z-index: 2;
background-image: url('../images/map.png');
}
```

and this is the call of my css file in the HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

The problem is that I got only a kind of an empty square with no picture inside...

What is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does Javascript have to do with this?

Comment: Why are you using the same image as the background and the button image?

Comment: The solution is probably this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1193338/1656568

Comment: It sounds like you aren't getting the correct path to your file for the image?...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use input type image.

Just use `input[type="submit"]` or `input[type="button"]`

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="location" />
```

CSS

```
#location{
     position: fixed;
     text-indent: -9999px;
     right: 10px;
     bottom: 20px;
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
     z-index: 2;
     background-color: url('./image/map.png';
     border: none;
}
```

Comment: it's always not working(this is the code):

http://pastebin.com/2iFYgDt4

Just a grey square with no picture as a background!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer define  element and set a background on it and also define a event handler for OnClick for this span as a button

```
<span style="background-image: url(../images/map.png)" onclick="clickFunction"> </span>
<script>
    function clickFunction() {
           // click event handler
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue with using a `background-image` on a button.  Here's a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YG7sX/.

HTML:

```
<button id = "location"></button>
```

CSS:

```
#location{
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/80x80) no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: it's always not working(this is the code):

http://pastebin.com/2iFYgDt4

Just a grey square with no picture as a background!

Comment: Here's another fiddle that uses `<input type = image />` and the image is setting nicely on it: http://jsfiddle.net/FdBLy/.  Are you sure that the path to the image is correct?