# Using image as submit button to delete image

Tags: css, button, submit

I have this line of code to delete images:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="deleteImage6" value="Delete">
</form>
```

This creates the old boring style button that says Delete. How can I change the button to appear as a 10x10 pixels sized image with red cross on it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change an input button image using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-an-input-button-image-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image submit button.

`<input type="image" src="/cross.png" border="0" alt="Delete" />`